# Locking in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, lock

I want to write a long-running shell script so that only one copy could be run at a time. If the script crashes, I want a new invocation of the script not to be stopped by a lock from the crashed invocation.

Is [`lockfile-*` set of utils](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile-create) the right thing to use? Is there a chance of a race condition while using them in a script?

Does `--use-pid` lift the 5-minutes limitation mentioned on the man page? My scripts run significantly longer.

I use an Ubuntu 10.10 instance on Amazon EC2; no NFS or something like that.

Comment: [BashFAQ 45](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045) recommends `flock`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/185451/1072112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating a lock can be done with the `lockfile` command or the `flock` system call or by creating a directory (which is an uninterupptable action) the second part is more tricky.

If the lock exists - how do you determine, if the lock belongs to a still running process?

The most common solution is to put the PID of the process into the lock-file.

Before trying to create a lock you have to check if the lock-file already exists. If so, check if the PID matches a running process that resembles the process that should create the lock. If this is not the case, remove the lock and recreate it.